# jQuery find is not working for links

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to `jQuery` and `AngularJS`. I have a resume as html document and I want to highlight a whole link if it contains a specific word. So,

```js
var checkString = $('div#htmleditior').find("a[href*=" + orphan.attributes.text + "]");
if (checkString.length > 0) {
  $('div#htmleditior').find("a[href*=" + orphan.attributes.text + "]")
                      .addClass('mark');
  isPresentInURL = true;
}
```

I have an array of words which I use to check if link contain it or not. But it is not working ? Also, I want to check if that word came 2nd time but is not in a URL. What should I do ?

Comment: is this html #htmleditior created by angulajs ?

Comment: If there's any spaces in the value of `orphan.attributes.text` then your selector won't work. It would really help to see a more complete sample of your code here

Comment: using a timeout function and htmleditior is just an id , I am using text-angular to show that html document, there is not space in the text.

Comment: Show the html I would like to see if the `a href` is a descendant of the `div` tag

Comment: <a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://example.com&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1491821372800000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHpgzCbQiGD6I2ga6aSE8GgmAFH7w" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit">http://example.com</a>

Comment: Yes it is  descendant of a div tag

Comment: Well, can you `console.log` the `checkString` to see what it output. If it not returning anything, then the selector is not working. You could try to test your selector using Chrome.

Comment: Without the html code, it is not possible to provide for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use find here, try this instead:

```
var checkString = $('div#htmleditior a[href*="' + orphan.attributes.text + '"]");
```

Comment: getting an error,  Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div#htmleditior a[href*=" + orphan.attributes.text + "]"

Comment: ops, forgot to add quates, please check it again @ganeshk